# A Confirmation Box On Exit

Tags: vbscript, hta

I want to have hta code such that:

When the user clicks on the "Close" button, it pops up a confirmation box.

If the user confirms "Yes", then it will quit otherwise it keeps running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778683/confirm-on-exit) this. The answer is the same, you can't do this. You could get familiar with [`onbeforeunload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event though.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you need a close button, it can be an input with button type (but in fact, any part of an HTML page can get a 'onclick' property, like a  in a table)

```
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick='F_closeConfirm'>
```

then the VB code should contain a function F_closeConfirm with something like this

```
Public Function F_closeConfirm()
    'one way to ask
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        'another way
        iAnswer = MsgBox("Like, really quit?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
        If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            'method to close parent windows or tab, can differ but it's another topic
            Window.Parent.Close
        End If
    End If
End Function
```